# "Fatal library error, lookup self" with pacstrap during Arch linux install

Tags: linux, installation, arch-linux

I'm following the Arch Linux install guide. When I run `pacstrap -K /mnt base linux linux-firmware`, everything goes smoothly until the following error message occurs:

```
(4/5) Check if user should be informed about rebooting after certain system package upgrades.
(5/5) Checking which packages need to be rebuilt
fatal library error, lookup self
pacstrap -K /mnt base linux linux-firmware 17.50s user 5.80s system 118% cpu 19.804 total
```

All my directories are mounted to /mnt. I'm using the default mirrorlist. Rebooting does not change anything. How can I fix this?

Edit: I believe this is a problem with dracut, because when installing `base` individually, nothing goes wrong. However, installing `linux` and `linux-firmware`, installation goes wrong.